# Can I request a MAP in a MuleESB Connector?

Tags: java, mule, jersey-client

I am writing a custom connector, using Jersey, and I need to create a @Processor that takes a MultivaluedMap as a parameter and pass it on to my Jersey query.

I would expect my @Connector to have

```
@Processor
public String query(MultiValuedMap<String,String> params) {
    ...
    return webResource.queryParams(params).get(String.class);
}
```

Then the xml.sample needs the example flow declaration but I can't find how to declare the parameter

```
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(myconnector:qry) -->
    <myconnector:qry params=" ??? " />
<!-- END_INCLUDE(myconnector:qry) -->
```

and the mule-config.xml needs the real parameter!

```
<flow name="testQuery">
    <myconnector:qry params=" ??? " />
</flow>
```

Alternatively I could simply insert a string into the Jersey request like

```
@Processor
public String query(String paramString) {
    return webResource. ??? .get(String.class);
}
```

but how do I append that String ("?age=45&language=en") to the query URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I came across the answer:

```
@Processor
Public void qry(List<String> param1,Map<String,String> param2) {
    ...
}
```

can be declared as

```
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(myconnector:qry) -->
    <myconnector:qry>
        <myconnector:param1 ref="" />
        <myconnector:param2 ref="" />
    </myconnector:qry>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(myconnector:qry) -->
```

Comment: Why much searching? Glancing at the XSD would have told you so, while familiarizing you with the outputs of DevKit.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, it does show the expected format but rather than hint, it openly declares it, very completely! Unfortunately, I didn't see it at the time. I think I was too dug into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XSD generated by DevKit: this will hint you as to the correct XML syntax to pass the map values to the message processor.